# How to make listview changes with search event in my bloc? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I have a ListView, that I need to transform when I call my SearchEvent, when i enter a value in the textfield my search works but when i remove the value from my textfield my list does not return to the previous state and remains the same even though i put the condition how do i make it so that when i remove the values ​​my list like this changed.
How can I make my list change when I remove values from textfield?

```
    TextField(
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          print(value);
                          _overallAttendanceBloc
                              .add(SearchEvent(search: value));
                        },
                      ),   



    on<SearchEvent>((event, emit) {
      List<OverallAttendanceModel> attendance = state is OverallAttendanceLoaded
          ? (state as OverallAttendanceLoaded).attendance
          : [];
      List<OverallAttendanceModel> filteredAttendance = attendance
          .where((element) =>
          element.name!.toLowerCase().contains(event.search.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
      if (event.search.trim().isEmpty) {
        filteredAttendance.replaceRange(0, filteredAttendance.length, attendance);
        emit(OverallAttendanceLoaded(attendance: filteredAttendance, date: ''));
      } else {
        emit(OverallAttendanceLoaded(attendance: filteredAttendance, date: ''));
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code may be it will help you, as  i understand you want to handle search funcationality where SerachEvent updates state of your ListView

```
on<SearchEvent>((event, emit) {
  List<OverallAttendanceModel> attendance = state is OverallAttendanceLoaded
      ? (state as OverallAttendanceLoaded).attendance
      : [];

  if (event.search.trim().isEmpty) {
    emit(OverallAttendanceLoaded(attendance: attendance, date: ''));
  } else {
    List<OverallAttendanceModel> filteredAttendance = attendance
        .where((element) =>
            element.name!.toLowerCase().contains(event.search.toLowerCase()))
        .toList();
    emit(OverallAttendanceLoaded(attendance: filteredAttendance, date: ''));
  }
});
```

Comment: I already tried this code, but for some reason it doesn't change my list when it's empty

Comment: try to print values to debug